# Auto increment form field

Tags: ms-access, update

I am working with a database, with  some forms. What I am trying to do is an auto increment field in my form. For example ID -- every time when I type some new record, this field ID should increment automatically like this: ID0001, ID0002 etc. I need a formula to put in before update to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using an AutoNumber column?  This is similar to the IDENTITY property in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

```
Where My_ID = ID0001, ID0002, ID0003…
IIF(Val(Right(DMax("[My_ID]","[MyTableName]"),4))+1<10,"ID000" & Val(Right(DMax("[My_ID]","[MyTableName]"),4))+1,
IIF(Val(Right(DMax("[My_ID]","[MyTableName]"),4))+1<100,"ID00" & Val(Right(DMax("[My_ID]","[MyTableName]"),4))+1,
IIF(Val(Right(DMax("[My_ID]","[MyTableName]"),4))+1<1000,"ID0" & Val(Right(DMax("[My_ID]","[MyTableName]"),4))+1,
"ID" & Val(Right(DMax("[My_ID]","[MyTableName]"),4))+1
)))
```

With this, you will be good for 9,999 unique ID numbers before going from a 6 character ID to 7 characters.

The formula display has extra carrage returns for visual effect which can be removed to provide a continuous string.

If you wish to use VBA, you might consider the following:

```
    Dim IDNum as Integer
    Dim NewID as String

    IDNum = Val(Right(DMax("[My_ID]","[MyTableName]"),4))+1 

    IF IDNum< 10 then
        NewID  = "ID000" & IDNum
    ElseIF IDNum< 100 then
        NewID  = "ID00" & IDNum
    ElseIF IDNum< 1000 then
        NewID  = "ID0" & IDNum
    Else
        NewID  = "ID" & IDNum
    EndIf

    Me.My_ID = NewID
```

I hope that this is helpful.

Comment: I think the unwieldy zero-padding could be replaced with a single-liner. My VB isn't very good (putting it mildly) but perhaps something like `"ID" & Right(CStr(10000 + IDNum), 4)` would do the job. And I think that would allow it to be integrated into the `IDNum` calculation one-liner, so in the end no variables would be needed at all: `"ID" & Right(CStr(10000 + Val(Right(DMax("[My_ID]","[MyTableName]"),4))+1), 4)`.